Second-order quadrangle mesh of a curved surface using Gmsh
Why am I obtaining a "two flat element" element instead of a one flat element, when using second-order mesh?
That is the .geo file
//+
Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, 100};
//+
Point(2) = {0.5, 0, 0, 100};
//+
Point(3) = {1, 0, 0, 100};
//+
Circle(1) = {3, 2, 1};
//+
Extrude {0, 0, 1} {
  Curve{1}; Layers {1}; Recombine;
}
//+
Curve Loop(1) = {1, 4, -2, -3};
//+
Transfinite Curve {1} = 3 Using Progression 1;
//+
Transfinite Curve {2} = 3 Using Progression 1;
//+
Transfinite Curve {4} = 3 Using Progression 1;
//+
Transfinite Curve {3} = 3 Using Progression 1;

Mesh.ElementOrder = 2;
Mesh 2;
Save "mesh.msh";

The following describes what I mean by "two" flat elements.

The difference is even more evident when considering a first-order element.

In both cases, I just have 2 elements. But for the second-order elements, it seems like the mesh has four elements.

The second order elements are 9 node non-flat quadrilaterals. The fact that they look like two "flat" elements is a plotting artifact. They are actually parabolically curved elements.
If you want to have a "flat" faced mesh which is discretized using higher order finite elements then you should generate a first order mesh, then impose your higher order basis on top of the flat elements. This would be call a "sub parametric" element since the order of the geometry representation is less than the fields discretization order.
